# Docker Container Connection Refused MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, containers, subnet

I have this docker-compose file:

```
networks:
    default:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 10.48.0.0/16
                  gateway: 10.48.0.1
services:
    haproxy:
        build: haproxy
        container_name: haproxy
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy/conf/:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/
            - ./haproxy/ssl/:/etc/ssl/xip.io/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks: 
            default:
                ipv4_address: 10.48.0.2

    server:
        build: server
        container_name: server
        restart: always
        environment:
            - ENV=env=production db=true
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        volumes:
            - ./server/config:/usr/src/app/config
        depends_on: 
            - haproxy
        networks: 
            default:
                ipv4_address: 10.48.0.4

    frontend:
        build: frontend
        container_name: frontend
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./frontend/config:/usr/src/app/config
        depends_on: 
            - server
        networks: 
            default:
                ipv4_address: 10.48.0.5
version: '2'
```

In order to deploy a backend server and a frontend interface inside a subnet defined in the range 10.48.0.0/16.
So I tried to assign fixed ip to each container. On Linux everything is ok, so I can reach 10.48.0.4_8081/api, but on MacOS when I try to do the same thing, I have **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. 
If I try to connect without using IP, but with localhost:8081/api, this is ok. But with multiple containers, I have to access directly with the IP.
Inside each container, if I try to ping the other ip address (example from container frontend with IP 10.48.0.5 I try to ping 10.48.0.4) everything is OK.
So my question is, How can I do in order make an http call to an api that is on another service? thanks for your help.

Comment: have you opened up the port in your firewall? turn your firewall off and see if it works

Comment: @RutgerVk hi, the firewall is not active on the mac yet

Comment: Are you just trying to make calls between your services, and to your services from outside?  You don't need any of this manual IP configuration to do that.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, the subnet in this case is necessary in order to assign a fixed ip to a container, otherwise it could be change and so the configuration for the applications too

Comment: You know that containers can address each other using the container name (or Docker Compose name) as a DNS name?

Comment: @DavidMaze I know, but the question is different. I don't have to call a container from inside another one, I have to call a service exposed by a container through a client (in this case a browser).

Answer (score 1):

I've read everywhere that is a well know situation under windows and mac, but not on linux, where is possible from the client side making request directly on the ip address of the container. This is not possible on mac and is still open an issue on github.
In this case, I've used haproxy in order to proxy requests to each container.